# Rails 4 - Date is mix-matching day and month after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, time, rubygems, rails-i18n

I'm using the `gem 'datetimepicker-rails'` and specifically using the date_picker in my `simple_form` as such:

```
<%= f.input :tripDate, :as => :date_picker, label: 'Pick-up Date', placeholder: 'Click icon on right', input_html: {data: {date_options: {showClose: true}}} %>
```

The input box for this field shows the correct output of the date in the format that I want but the date in the database that's saved is being saved with the month and day being changed with each other.

The documentation points out changing `config/locales/en.yml` so I changed it to this format:

```
en:
  datepicker:
    dformat: '%m/%d/%Y'               # display format of the date (this is the default, can be ommited)
    pformat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'             # picking format of the date (this is the default, can be ommited)
  timepicker:
    dformat: '%R'                     # display format of the time (this is the default, can be ommited)
    pformat: 'hh:mm A'                # picking format of the time (this is the default, can be ommited)
    dayViewHeaderFormat: 'MMMM YYYY'  # picking format of the time (this is the default, can be ommited)
```

**Expected** input to DB: **2016/04/09**

**Actual** input to DB after locales/en.yml changes: **2016/09/04**

so this is showing me that changing the format is somehow changing the day and month. The parameter that's committed to the DB is: `["tripDate", "2016-09-04"]`

But the rails log messages gives me the correct date output: `Started POST "/reservations" for ::1 at 2016-04-09 09:00:21 -0400`

This leads me to believe it's something wrong with the gem possibly.

I'm not doing any other changes to the tripDate attribute before saving. Can someone explain what is going on and what a solution would be?

Comment: How are you inspecting the created record? Is the data in the database correct or is it just the display of it?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I've tried several methods, Im looking at the logs in the terminal on my local machine then I've ran rails console pulling the column printing it and also looking at the retrieved data in my application.

Comment: no matter what the format of your input, the data stored in the db has the same format - check in the rails console that the date has the correct value (use strftime to reformat if you want). If that produces correct result but your views don't, then the problem is with how the views format the data, if the data in the db isn't correct then the problem is your input. Figure out which one it is and update your question accordingly (it could conceivably be both in which case focus on getting the right data in the db first)

Comment: will continue checking tomorroe since it is getting late. @FrederickCheung

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my dilemma was solved by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405703/rails-simple-form-bootstrap-and-datepicker) SO post. More specifically the very last solution given to the problem which said to do something along these lines:

```
def create
 .....
 @person.dob = DateTime.strptime(params[:person][:dob], '%m/%d/%Y').to_date
 .....
 @person.save
 .....
end
```