# Helper date_select. How validate dates 30 and 31 of february?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model Freelancer and tables freelancers with property birthday, type date.

**freelancers/edit.html.erb**

```
<li class="form-fields__group form-fields__group_birthdate">
        <label for="freelancer_birth_date">Birthday</label>
        <div class= "field">
          <%= f.date_select :birthday, { prompt: { day: 'Select day', 
                                                  month: 'Select month', 
                                                  year: 'Select year' },
                                include_blank: true, start_year: Time.now.year - 70}, 
                                                    { class: 'form-control_medium'} %>
        </div>
      </li>
```

If I selcet february 30 or 31 return value 3 march. How me validate value date 30 and 31 if I selected february? Thank you

Comment: standard date_select so pure. You can use custom datetime inputs (e.g. Bootstrap)

Comment: How you display in more detail?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405703/rails-simple-form-bootstrap-and-datepicker

Comment: I a bit perplexed on why this would give you the date 3/3. The input is passed to `Date.new` and if you try to do `Date.new(2016, 2, 30)` it gives `ArgumentError: invalid date input`. You might want to try a gem like  [date_validator](https://github.com/codegram/date_validator)